# Android Change App State Based on Update to Database/Other External Influence

Tags: java, android, database

I've designed a game for Android and want to be able to send my users notifications at a later date to, say, promote a sequel to my game.

However, I currently don't know if/when I will create a sequel so I don't know if/when I want to display this notification or what it will say.

I'm thinking I'll have to query a database or website or something every time a user opens the app and if there's something new there display it to them. However, I've never done something like this before and am not really sure where to start. Are there any services I could use to simplify this problem?

(Sorry for not posting any code, but I'm just trying to get an idea of how approach the issue.)

Comment: Maybe [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) is your solution.. did you checked it?

Comment: Yes! It looks like that will solve my problem. I knew there had to be a simple solution, I just couldn't find it. Thanks!